# Hardware Virtualization not possible, virtualbox alternatives?

Tags: software-recommendation, virtualbox, virtualization, cpu, bios

I have two processors, but virtualbox won't accept that unless I have hardware virtualization (vt-x) enabled, for which my bios setup doesn't give an option, and the option was never added in bios upgrades.  As you might tell, I've done some pretty extensive research trying to get this set up.  My issue is that, setting it up with just one processor, the guest is running at 100% of its cpu.  Is there some other nice gui (couldn't figure out qemu/qemu-kvm) that wouldn't require vt-x to be enabled in order to take advantage of my actual hardware?

Xubuntu Trusty

HP Compaq dc5100 slim

bios v1.07

Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.00GHz

Comment: I might be wrong but I think it's 4th generation or something like that (the predecessor is the pentium III). http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/320298-28-pentium-dual-core

Comment: I ended up just setting my daughter up with an old XP machine that pretty much only runs this school CD.  I've given up on virtualization for the foreseeable future.  Thanks @mchid for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

`gnome-boxes` is a nice gui, it takes advantage of `qemu` and it doesn't seem to be as picky as Virtualbox (you can use wifi etc). Open a terminal and type the following command to install it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-boxes
```

more info: [wiki.gnome.org](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Boxes?action=show&redirect=Boxes)

Comment: hmmm, in synaptic, the description specifically says hardware virtualization is necessary, but I'll give it a test drive.  thanks for the response.

Comment: If you're able to use qemu, boxes is a frontend GUI for qemu.

Comment: @undrline You should be able to run a virtualmachine but without VT you will only be able to run i386 or x86 (x86_64 or amd64 require VT or equiv.) but it will be slow.

Comment: I don't mind x86 32 bit stuff.  Really, I have two uses.  One is a school cd that my daughter has that won't work under Wine (if she can't work on it at home, she'll have to stay after school, and it makes ubuntu look bad in the eyes of the future gen), and the other is to see if I can get DC Universe Online to work (it complains that X11 is not a valid graphics card when I use it under Wine or PlayOnLinux).  Neither require anything but Windows 32 bit.

Comment: can't figure out how to get gnome-boxes to use an ova instead of an iso, so I haven't really been able to test it.

Comment: @undrline If an ova will work, you can right click on the file and select to open the file using gnome-boxes.